# setApplicationIconBadgeNumber when called multiple times does not update the badge

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am working on an application where in I have to update the badge shown in the app icon multiple times. However, what I have noted is that, the setApplicationIconBadgeNumber api just works once during the lifetime of the app. I have tries using the UILocalNotification, and it works then but, I dont want to follow that route. Have you guys faced a similar problem. If yes, any pointers?

Regards
Nitin

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in iOS. It's still present today in 6.0.1, where I just fixed it with a work-around:

```
    // Clear app badge number. Work-around for bug in iOS.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

Comment: Still continues with ios 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Might the problem be from where you are calling it?

Wrong:

```
// This is only called once during application lifecycle
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
}
```

Correct:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
}
```